# c# MongoDB Repo reference for Delete(string id) function won't accept being passed string DAO parameter

Tags: c#, mongodb, dao, data-access-layer

I'm trying to create a Delete function in a DAL EmployeeDAO, as seen here:

```
public long Delete(string Id)
    {
        HelpdeskRepository repo = new HelpdeskRepository(new DbContext());
        long deleteFlag = 0;
        if (Id.Count() > 0)
        {
            repo.Delete(Id.GetIdAsString());
            deleteFlag = 1;
            return deleteFlag;// if found count = 1 == true
        }
        else
        {
            return deleteFlag;
        }
    }
```

However, the `repo.Delete(Id.GetIdAsString());` won't work, giving me the error

> Cs1061 
>   Error  CS1061  'string' does not contain a definition for 'GetIdAsString' and >no extension method 'GetIdAsString' accepting a first argument of type 'string' >could be found

The Repository (repo) function it is referencing is thus:

```
public long Delete<HelpdeskEntity>(string id)
    {
        var filter = new FilterDefinitionBuilder<HelpdeskEntity>().Eq("Id", new ObjectId(id));
        var collection = GetCollection<HelpdeskEntity>();
        var deleteRes = collection.DeleteOne(filter);
        return deleteRes.DeletedCount;
    }
```

and the GetIdAsString() function:

```
public string GetIdAsString()
    {
        return this.Id.ToString();
    }
```

I do not understand why the Id parameter won't work in the `repo.Delete` call either, as Delete accepts string parameters and Id is of type string.

Any thoughts, or better ways to achieve this? I cannot use Insert/async/await methods of creation for this due to future project requirements relying on repository methods, so it must be done using the `repo.Delete` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May I ask where do you define `GetIdAsString()` method ?  The `Id` in your `Delete(string Id)` is already a `string` and the `string` class has no extension method `GetIdAsString()` hence the error occurs.

And in the `Delete<HelpdeskEntity>(string id)` the parameter `id` is already a `string` so it makes no sense to me to have the `GetIdAsString()` method. Just use `repo.Delete(Id)`.

Comment: I had fixed the issue but this is the closest to the solution. You were correct in that I should just use my repo.Delete(Id) function, I simply needed to make it repo.Delete<Employee>(Id); to get it to work. I hadn't realized that the <HelpdeskEntity> in the IRepository Delete function meant that I needed to pass it a type of HelpdeskEntity, of which Employee would be the relevant one here.

Answer (score 0):

So firstly, you are referencing GetIsAsString() as if it is an extension method here:

```
repo.Delete(Id.GetIdAsString());
```

If you want it to be a extension method it should look something like this (within a static class)

```
public static string GetIdAsString(this ObjectId id)
{
    return id.ToString();
}
```

Otherwise, reference it like this if it is within the same class as your Id property:

```
repo.Delete(GetIdAsString());
```

But to be honest, I don't understand the purpose of the GetIdAsString() method.

It is being called on the Id parameter which is already a string variable.

So this should work

```
repo.Delete(Id);
```

Also, i think you will want to be referencing _id here, and you shouldn't need to cast it to ObjectId either

```
var filter = new FilterDefinitionBuilder<HelpdeskEntity>().Eq("_id", id);
```